# Django - 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_total_addon_price'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here I am trying to call a function of a different model class. When trying to call this function it throws an error sayiing 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_total_addon_price'

In `Cart(models.Model)` I am trying to call the function `get_total_addon_price` of the model `AddonCartItem`

```
def get_total(self):
        c_cart_item = 0
        a_cart_item = 0
        cart_total = 0

        if self.addon_item.get_total_addon_price != 0:
```

But it throws an error

Can anyone please help me with this. I have added the full `models.py` and the `error Traceback`

`models.py`

```
class ComboCartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    combo = models.ForeignKey(Combo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.combo.title}"
        # return str(self.id)

    def get_total_combo_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.combo.combo_regular_price

    def get_total_combo_sale_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.combo.combo_sale_price

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_combo_price() - self.get_total_combo_sale_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.combo.combo_sale_price:
            return self.get_total_combo_sale_price()
        return self.get_total_combo_price

class AddonCartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    addon = models.ForeignKey(Addon, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    addon_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.addon.name}"
        # return str(self.id)

    def get_total_addon_price(self):
        addon_total = 0
        addon_total = self.quantity * self.addon.price
        self.addon_total = addon_total
        self.save()
        return self.quantity * self.addon.price

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    combo_item = models.ManyToManyField(ComboCartItem, blank=True, null=True)
    addon_item = models.ManyToManyField(AddonCartItem, blank=True, null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    cart_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def get_total(self):
        c_cart_item = 0
        a_cart_item = 0
        cart_total = 0

        if self.addon_item.get_total_addon_price != 0:
            for combo_cart_item in self.combo_item.all():
                c_cart_item += combo_cart_item.get_final_price()
            for addon_cart_item in self.addon_item.all():
                a_cart_item += addon_cart_item.get_total_addon_price()
            cart_total = c_cart_item + a_cart_item
            self.cart_total = cart_total
            self.save()
            return cart_total
        else:
            for cart_item in self.combo_item.all():
                cart_total += cart_item.get_final_price()
            self.cart_total = cart_total
            self.save()
            return cart_total
```

`Traceback`

```
Internal Server Error: /carts/cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in 
_get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in 
_get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\monday\carts\views.py", line 12, in cart
    return render(request, 'carts/cart-view.html', context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render    
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 986, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "C:\monday\carts\models.py", line 94, in get_total
    if self.addon_item.get_total_addon_price != 0:
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_total_addon_price'
[22/May/2020 20:43:38] "GET /carts/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 172420
```

Comment: Since this is the reverse of a `ForeignKey`, there can be zero, one or more `AddonCartItem`s, hence you can not call the method on a collection of items.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So to run this block of code `if self.addon_item.get_total_addon_price != 0:` How should I check the condition or how can I run this block?

Comment: you can for example iterate over `for item self.addon_item.all()`, and check if all/any (depending on what you want to do) is zero.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I actually tried doing that `for a in self.addon_item.all():` `a = a.addon.get_total_addon_price()`. Then I wrote the condition as `if a != 0:`. It doesn't throw any error but it also doesn't run the block

Comment: that is possible, since there are not *per se* any `AddonItem`s that are *linked* to that `ComboCartItem`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry I didnt understand